# What would be the best way to check if any of the keys in an array of objects contain a value from an object of arrays array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I want to create a filter system by checking if any of the project technologies exist in the `arrOfObjs.name`'s. If it does, then it will pass the filter and be included/shown to the DOM. More specifically a computed value in VueJS.

Example:

```
arrOfObjs = [{name: 'test1', image: 'testing1'}, {name: 'test2', image:'testing2'}]
projects: 
[
      {
        name: "testproject",
        description: "lorem ipsum",
        technologies: ["test2", "test7", "test3"]
      },
      {
        name: "atest",
        description: "lorem ipsum",
        technologies: ["test1", "test2", "test5"]
      },
]
```

My attempt:

```
computed: {
  myComputedVal () {
    projs = []
    this.projects.forEach(p => {
      p.technologies.forEach(t => {
        this.arrOfObjs.filter(o => {
          if (o.name == t) {
            return p // maybe projs = [...projs, p] and return projs
          }
        })
      })
    })
  }
}
```

I want to check if ANY of the values in technologies exist in `arrOfObjs.name`, if it does, then return the project or push it to an array to later return this array of objects as a computed value. At the moment, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with the below code snippet you can filter out those projects where any of the `technologies` are present in the `arrOfObjs` array's `name` properties.

Using [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) you can get all the names into an array as strings first. Then using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as you wanted originally and with using [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) combination just filter out the projects if any of the technologies elements are represented in `names` array like:

`({technologies}) => technologies.some(t => names.includes(t))`

If you would like to check if all the elements are present, then suggest to use `every()` like:

`({technologies}) => technologies.every(t => names.includes(t))`

Possible solution - representing the example with `some()`:

```js
const arrOfObjs = [{name: 'test1', image: 'testing1'}, {name: 'test2', image:'testing2'}],
      projects = [{name: "testproject",description: "lorem ipsum",technologies: ["test2", "test7", "test3"]}, {name: "atest",description: "Lorem ipsum", technologies: ["test1", "test2", "test5"] }];

const names = arrOfObjs.flatMap(e => e.name);
const result = projects.filter(
   ({technologies}) =>
      technologies.some(t => names.includes(t)
      // technologies.every(t => names.includes(t) // if all needed
   )
);

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!